# IoC/DI - How to get same instance from different applications?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have two applications (web service and backend application) and these applications use Castle Windsor IoC container from a helper project to get instances of libraries such as session, log, cache and etc. Everything is okay until here but I cannot access the same instance on each application. When I change something on cache from backend application and reload the cache by getting instance from IoC, it affects only backend application. Is there any idea, how can I get and set same instance of IoC from different applications?

This is the mechanism of my structure:

```
App A: Project 1
App B: Project 2
App C: Helper

App C loads IoC with singleton lifestyle.
App A and App B uses App C to get instances to use.
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Is *App C* really an application, or is it a library? Are *App A* and *App B* running in the same process?

Comment: Actually it is a helper library and other applications (App A and App B) have reference of that library to use.

Comment: An instance can only be shared between applications by [marshaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) the object (usually using serialization). This is not that easy, and does not likely involve using DI. But, my guess is that is not what you are asking to do. You need to give specifics. Are these applications 2 different websites or executables? Why do you have 2 applications if both of them need the same instance from the library? A simple way to solve this would be to have one application that uses a singleton instance of the object.

Comment: you should control your objects from top not from down. App A and App B should have their own IOC not C. C should just have interfaces and shouldn't know anything about A or B.